Wi-Fi not working after noble upgrade from 22.04lts to 24.04lts
My software updater had a upgrade to 24.04lts  I was on 22.04 with all the latest updates to date.  I am run dual boot  win and Ubuntu with Ubuntu and Cinnamon Linux choice’s at startup. My Wi-Fi is ac1900 driver 8814au and Everything was working perfect until I the upgrade to 24.04lts . Now the Wi-Fi is not working after noble upgrade from 22.04lts to 24.04lts .   I tried terminal Apt updates and all the other form suggestions with no help it still does not work.  There is not even Wi-Fi option in the settings now.  So I restored my previous version from a backup and everything again  is back with updated version 22.04lts   This problem bug needs to be fixed as I see many others with the same issue on this upgrade. This is a bad bug that needs to be addressed before another release of this version.

see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1519273/1698042

This question is similar to: Internet is not working after upgrading to ubuntu 24.04. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If this is really a bug situation that needs to be fixed, perhaps @user1920680  could consider reporting it.

Your current driver is not working. If the driver doesn't install you will not see the Wi-Fi graphics interface. Take a look at the following GitHub project which is about your driver (8814au): https://github.com/morrownr/8814au
Don't forget to remove the old driver before installing the new one (see below). You will have to build the driver yourself but there are full instructions on the site. I'm quoting here the instructions relevant to Ubuntu:

Installation Information
Warning: Installing multiple out-of-kernel drivers for the same hardware usually does not end well. The install-driver.sh script has the capability to detect and remove many conflicting drivers but not all. If this driver does not work well after installation and you have previously installed a driver that you did not remove, it is suggested that you run the following command in an effort to determine if you need to take action to manually remove conflicting drivers:
sudo dkms status

Warning: If you decide to do a distro upgrade, which will likely install a new version of kernel such as 5.15 to 6.1, you need to upgrade this driver with the newest available code before performing the disto upgrade. Use the following commands in the driver directory:
git pull
sudo ./install-driver.sh

Temporary internet access is required for installation. There are numerous ways to enable temporary internet access depending on your hardware and situation. One method is to use tethering from a phone.. Another method is to keep a WiFi adapter that uses an in-kernel driver in your toolkit.
You will need to use the terminal interface. The quick way to open a terminal: Ctrl+Alt+T (hold down on the Ctrl and Alt keys then press the T key).
An alternative terminal is to use SSH (Secure Shell) from the same or from another computer, in which case you will be in a suitable terminal after logging in, but this step requires that an SSH daemon/server has already been configured. (There are lots of SSH guides available, e.g., for the Raspberry Pi and for Ubuntu. Do not forget to secure the SSH server.)
You will need to have sufficient access rights to use sudo so that commands can be executed as the root user. (If the command sudo echo Yes returns "Yes", with or without having to enter your password, you do have sufficient access rights.)
DKMS is used for the installation, if available. DKMS is a system utility which will automatically recompile and reinstall this driver when a new kernel is installed. DKMS is provided by and maintained by Dell.
It is recommended that you do not delete the driver directory after installation as the directory contains information and scripts that you may need in the future.
Secure Boot: see FAQ.
Installation Steps
Step 1: Open a terminal (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+T)
Step 2: Update and upgrade system packages (select the option for the distro you are using)
[...]

Option for Debian based distributions such as Ubuntu, Kali, Armbian and Raspberry Pi OS
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade



[...]
Note: It is recommended that you reboot your system at this point. The rest of the installation will appreciate having a fully up-to-date system to work with. The installation can then be continued with Step 3.
sudo reboot

Step 3: Install the required packages (select the option for the distro you are using)
[...]
Development Environment Requirements: (package names may vary by distro)

Mandatory packages: gcc make bc kernel-headers build-essential git
Highly recommended packages: dkms rfkill iw ip
Mandatory packages if Secure Boot is active: openssl sign-file mokutil

Note: The below options should take care of the mandatory and highly recommended requirements. If Secure Boot is active on your system, please also install the mandatory packages for Secure Boot as shown above.
[...]

Option for Ubuntu (all official flavors) and the numerous Ubuntu based distros
 sudo apt install -y build-essential dkms git iw



[...]
Step 4: Create a directory to hold the downloaded driver
mkdir -p ~/src

Step 5: Move to the newly created directory
cd ~/src

Step 6: Download the driver
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8814au.git

Step 7: Move to the newly created driver directory
cd ~/src/8814au

Step 8: Run the installation script (install-driver.sh)
Note: It is recommended that you terminate running apps so as to provide the maximum amount of RAM to the compilation process.
Note: For automated builds (non-interactive), use NoPrompt as an option.
sudo ./install-driver.sh

or
sudo sh install-driver.sh

Note: If you elect to skip the reboot at the end of the installation script, the driver may not load immediately and the driver options will not be applied. Rebooting is strongly recommended.

